# Angular 2/4: How to show all navigation entries of children modules in the parent level navigation bar?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

In the first version of the UI design of my project, there are two levels of navigations. The root level, only 4 links: feature groups A, B, C, and D. Each feature group has its own features: A1, A2...B1, B2....D1, D2. When a user click link "A" on the app root page, then all the features of group A will show on a sub navigation bar.

I implemented the app like this: created 4 feature modules A, B, C and D. Each module has its own routing config (e.g: a-routing.module.ts under folder A). The second level navigation bar is written in each feature modules's component template, e.g.: a.component.html. Everything has been fine.

Now the team has changed the GUI design. There is a dropdown menu on the root level navigation bar. Links to all feature pages are assembled in this dropdown menu bar. What is the best way to refactor my implementation to fit this new dropdown menu bar? (I will have to push all the 2-level navi links to 1-level navi template now. app.component.html has be changed to contain all these links. But do I have to refactor other files too? And how?)

Angular 2 is relatively new to me, I'm still learning, many thanks in advance for any help.

Current app.component.html looks like this:

```html
<h1>My App</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" >Dashboard</a>
      <a routerLink="servicecatalog" routerLinkActive="active">Service Catalog</a>
      <a routerLink="administration" routerLinkActive="active" >Administration</a>
      <a routerLink="usermenu" routerLinkActive="active" >Profile</a>
    </nav>    
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Current app-routing.module.ts looks like this (sans imports):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ PageNotFoundComponent ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
    
    
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Component template of one of the children module looks like this:

```html
<ul>
 <li><a routerLink="dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li><a routerLink="service-status" routerLinkActive="active">Service Status</a></li>
 <li><a routerLink="service-usage" routerLinkActive="active">Service
   Usage</a></li>
 <li><a routerLink="system-status" routerLinkActive="active">System
   Status</a></li>
 <li *ngFor="let item of externalHooks">
 <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/binded-ui', item.uri]" routerLinkActive="active">{{item.caption}}</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The corresponding child routing config looks like this (sans imports):

```js
const monitoringRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: MonitoringComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: 'service-status', component: ServiceStatusComponent },
            { path: 'service-usage', component: ServiceUsageComponent },
            { path: 'system-status', component: SystemStatusComponent },
            { path: 'binded-ui/:uri', component: UIBindingComponent }
        ]
    }   
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(monitoringRoutes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class MonitoringRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried. It is relatively straightforward. Basically I only need to move the entries in the module html to the root html, and make some slight change to the routerLink. For example, this line:

```html
<li><a routerLink="service-status" routerLinkActive="active">Service Status</a></li>
```

when moved to app.component.html, changed be changed to

```
<li><a routerLink="/dashboard/service-status" routerLinkActive="active">Service Status</a></li>
```

Basically that's it. The other typescript files do not need change in my case. But if there was some router guard, maybe change will be needed. I don't know. I'm building router guard into the migrated code now.